# C# Simple equivalent to Enum but with multiple data types?

Tags: c#

Is there a better solution for a public predefined data source which can be global, located in the namespace like **Enum**, easy to reach without using constructors but to hold multiple datatypes like a tiny Database.
My best approach so far is this :

```
 public class PublicData
    {

        int[] Values = { 89, 11, 4, 12, 4, 24, 12 };

        string[] Names = { "item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5", "item6", "item7" };

        bool[] Logics = { true, true, false, false, false, true, true };

        public int GetValue(int i)
        {
            return Values[i];
        }

        public string GetName(int i)
        {
            return Names[i];
        }

        public bool GetLogic(int i)
        {
            return Logics[i];
        }

    }
```

And the simplest way to use it is :

```
TextBox.Text = new PublicData.GetName(intReference);
CheckBox.Checked = new PublicData.GetLogic(intReference);
```

But I still wonder if there is a better way like Enums which is lighter and doesn't require any constructors.

Comment: You could make `PublicData` a [`static` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members).

Comment: Try the [SmartEnum](https://github.com/ardalis/SmartEnum)

Comment: Are the different arrays supposed to be related to each other in some way or are they independent?

Comment: @Charlieface yes they are, I had to use a class because enum holds a pair of values while in my case i needed more.

Comment: Sounds like you need a proper class to store all three values together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use it myself for as long as I could since it makes unit testing more difficult:  If you make the class Static, then no `new` keyword is needed.

```cs
public static class PublicData {
    private static readonly int[] Values = { 89, 11, 4, 12, 4, 24, 12 };
    private static readonly string[] Names = { "item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5", "item6", "item7" };
    private static readonly bool[] Logics = { true, true, false, false, false, true, true };

    public static int GetValue(int i) { return Values[i]; }
    public static string GetName(int i) { return Names[i]; }
    public static bool GetLogic(int i ) { return Logics[i]; }
}
```

The usage is the same but no `new` keyword is needed, as I already mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

One option without external dependencies may be using nested static classes:

```cs
public static class PublicData
{
    public static class Item1
    {
        public static string Name => "item1";
        public static int Value => 89;
        public static bool Logic => true;
    }

    public static class Item2
    {
        public static string Name => "item2";
        public static int Value => 11;
        public static bool Logic => true;
    }

    public static class Item3
    {
        public static int Value => 4;
        public static string Name => "item3";
        public static bool Logic => false;
    }
}
```

The usage

```cs
var value1 = PublicData.Item1.Value;
var name1 = PublicData.Item1.Name;
var logic1 = PublicData.Item1.Logic;

var value2 = PublicData.Item2.Value;
var name2 = PublicData.Item2.Name;
var logic2 = PublicData.Item2.Logic;
```

Another option is using [SmartEnum](https://github.com/ardalis/SmartEnum).
For .NET7+ use the latest version of the package. For older .NET versions use `2.1.0`

```cs
public class Items : SmartEnum<Items>
{
    public static Items Item1 { get; } = new("item1", 89, true);
    public static Items Item2 { get; } = new("item2", 11, true);
    public static Items Item3 { get; } = new("item3", 4, false);

    private Items(string name, int value, bool logic) : base(name, value)
    {
        Logic = logic;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public bool Logic { get; set; }
}
```

The usage:

```cs
var value1 = Items.Item1.Value;
var name1 = Items.Item1.Name;
var logic1 = Items.Item1.Logic;

var value2 = Items.Item2.Value;
var name2 = Items.Item2.Name;
var logic2 = Items.Item2.Logic;
```